# iPhone SDK: disable auto creation of dot (.) in text field (or textview)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, autocomplete, sdk, autocorrect

I've disabled auto-correction type for my text field,
and it does not show any other auto-correction,

but it still automatically creates a dot (.) when I press space key twice.

For example,
if I write "test" and press space key twice,
it automatically changes into "test. "

Anyone knows how to disable this feature?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Comment: Not exactly to disable the function, but I found a kind of workaround which i posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one solution - it uses UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification because this occurs after the auto-correction applies.

1. Set the delegate for the text field
2. Set up a notification

   `- (void) viewDidLoad {

       ...

       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

       selector:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)

       name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:tfTitle];

       }`
3. Then, notification handler
   `- (void)textFieldDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification

   {

       if ( [textField.text rangeOfString:@". "].length ) {

       // Change text

       textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@". " withString:@"  "];

   }

   }`

Comment: But lets say I did enter a ". " and not "  ". Wouldn't this create an issue there

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if you hook up a text field delegate and then implement the following method:

```
-(BOOL)shouldReplaceCharactersInRange:(NSRange)aRage withString:(NSString *)aString
```

You may be able to check aString for the autocorrected string (maybe @". ") and then just return NO. This will hopefully not allow the @"  " to be replaced with @". "

Comment: Hi Bisbo,

I tried your suggestion, and found that the auto-correction (double tap of space into period) occurs after this method is called, and the change does not call this method to check. Thanks anyway, and please let me know if you have any other idea.

Comment: Ahh, oh well, was just a thought :-)

Comment: That works if you check for double spaces, see that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576561/iphone-disable-the-double-tap-spacebar-for-shortcut/3023716#3023716