# iPhone virtual keyboard bug

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator

In iPhone virtual keyboard...

1.Change the alphabetical keypad view to numerical view.

2.Tap on the single quote(') button the view changes to alphabetical.

3.In this view tapping on space twice displays a fullstop.

I don't know whether it is apple bug or feature, How to fix this issue through coding?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug, this is a feature.

(Apple deliberately make pressing `'` switch back to the alphabetic plane for contractions like "Peter's".)

(And tapping space twice gives a period is also a feature. [It's even documented](http://www.apple.com/iphone/how-to/index.html#basics.typing).)

If you want to modify this feature, the whole UIKBKeyboard class of the keyboard layout needs to be changed at runtime, which means "private API" etc.

Comment: after automatically switching back to alphabetic plane, when i tap space twice it display fullstop... is it feature or bug?.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may help: [iPhone: Disable the "double-tap spacebar for ." shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576561/iphone-disable-the-double-tap-spacebar-for-shortcut/2587926#2587926)