# Double-spaced textview in CocoaTouch (iPhone)

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextview

Can I have a double-spaced UITextView? I mean, so that it retains its formatting when I edit it?

I need to display graphical elements in between the lines of text. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Replied to wrong question.

Answer is for question here:
[iPhone: Disable the "double-tap spacebar for ." shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576561/iphone-disable-the-double-tap-spacebar-for-shortcut/3023716#3023716)

Put this in your delegate class:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{


 //Check for double space

 if (range.location > 0 && [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[string characterAtIndex:0]] && [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[[textField text] characterAtIndex:range.location - 1]])
  return NO;

return YES;
}
```