# Two blank space in UITextView automatically inserts a . (fullstop) after text in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I have a UITextView where I am inserting comma separated values. but when ever I insert any text and gives two or more space after it. It automatically appends the FULL STOP after last text.

Is it due to Phone setting? Even if yes. How can we prevent it?

**EDIT** To reproduce it.. Enter any word in UITextView and then try to apply two spaces. It will automatically add fullstop at the end of hte word :)

Comment: It is not happening when I do it, can you tell us more about it, like how are you inserting text and may be what text are inserting..

Comment: Yes i have tried it with uitextview only and still its not putting any periods(.) for two spaces, you might want to check your string once again in the log before setting the text property of your textview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
//Check for double space
return !(range.location > 0 &&
         [text length] > 0 &&
         [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[text characterAtIndex:0]] &&
         [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[[textView text] characterAtIndex:range.location - 1]]);

}
```

Above code will limit user to enter more than one blank space.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the setting **'.' shortcut** in keyboard settings.

Answer (score 2):

Apple describes the behaviour as: "Double tapping the space bar will insert a period followed by a space", and it is indeed an iOS system setting (Settings/General/Keyboard/**"." Shortcut**).

The user can disable the behaviour, but disabling it by code on a specific UITextView seems difficult - see [iPhone: Disable the "double-tap spacebar for ." shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576561/iphone-disable-the-double-tap-spacebar-for-shortcut)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the previous and the replacement characters are both empty space, and do the replacement yourself instead of iOS to have a chance to get the second empty space.

Returning false from the handler achieves this:

```
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool 
    {
    
    guard let textViewText = textView.text, range.location > 0 else {
      return true
    }
    
    let previousCharIndex = textViewText.index(textViewText.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location - 1)
    let previousChar = textViewText[previousCharIndex]
    
    if previousChar == " " && text == " " {
      let insertionPoint = textViewText.index(textViewText.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location)
      textView.text?.insert(" ", at: insertionPoint)
      return false
    }
    
    return true 
    }
```