# How to disable autofill on the TextField for a macOS?

Tags: macos, swiftui, autofill

I'm doing the following to disable all auto-filling in my macOS app:

```
            Text("ID:")
            TextField("", text: bindingCurrentID)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
```

But it doesn't do anything. If I start typing spaces into that text field (after the text that is already there) the OS automatically adds a period at the end.

How do I disable it? Or remove all typex of automatic completion and let only user-typed stuff into that field?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854058/two-blank-space-in-uitextview-automatically-inserts-a-fullstop-after-text-in

Comment: @ChrisR: I'm asking for a macOS. Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: of course you can always disable it in system preferences ... but I suppose you want to do it programmatically, and the link might give you hints on how to do it.

Comment: No, I don't want it disabled globally. So I suppose there's no way to do it in the current `TextField`. Oh well...

Comment: ok I think I got a possible way ... see answer.

Answer (score 0):

`.disableAutocorrection()` is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/disableautocorrection(_:)). You should use `.autocorrectionDisabled()` instead. See documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/autocorrectiondisabled(_:)).

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Email", text: $text)
            .autocorrectionDisabled() // prevents automatic correction from the system.
    }
}
```

Comment: It still does it when I use `.autocorrectionDisabled()`

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach:

```
            TextField("", text: $input)
                .autocorrectionDisabled(true)
            
                .onChange(of: input) { _ in
                    input = input.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "  ")
                }
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks. But what if someone types in a period on purpose.

Comment: I'm aware it's a hack :) I also found this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/121828

Comment: Hmm, that `NSAutomaticPeriodSubstitutionEnabled` is interesting. But how do you set it to false?

Comment: `UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "NSAutomaticPeriodSubstitutionEnabled")`

Comment: Chris, that did it. Thanks! Although I noticed that it's a user-global setting. Right? Which is less than ideal. Idk why there's no control specific setting to disable it. I understand it for iOS. But on a Mac?

Comment: I agree. always a pain to struggle against unwanted machine "intelligence" ;)