# is this known behavior of uitextfield and how to disable it?

Tags: xcode, cocoa

when I type in uitextfield something followed by multiple spaces it replaces the first space with ., I can delete it and then it will not happen in this particular input.
Is this coming because of the auto-correction?
Is this behavior is known, how to disable itwithout disabling the auto-correction?
Thanks.
Victor

Answer (score 2):

This is standard iOS typing behaviour. When your typing sentences you don't need to type . You just press 2 spaces and it does it for you.
It can be disabled in the general phone settings.

The accepted answer here will help you ignore it [iPhone: Disable the "double-tap spacebar for ." shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576561/iphone-disable-the-double-tap-spacebar-for-shortcut)

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature that the user can enable/disable. Go to the iPhone/iPad settings -> General -> Keyboard -> "." Shortcut.