# While validating email, if space is pressed twice, a full-stop gets appeared automatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, email-validation

I am using the normal regular expression which most of us are using for Email validation.

Problem : Suppose if my Email id is : a@a.com, then after "com" if I press space twice, a full - stop gets appeared automatically.

I am using following code for validating email.

```
- (BOOL)validateEmailWithString:(NSString*)email
{
    NSLog(@"helloo in validate");
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"; 
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; 
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];
}
```

How do I avoid this full-stop ????

As I am a newbie to iphone development, Please help me out !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full stop appearing after two spaces is normal behavior. Most users know this and won't be surprised when it happens. You can turn it off in the settings (General->Keyboard->"." Shortcut).

If you really want to prevent it from happening, you can use the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6113117/74118). Note that you'll have to set up the text field delegate for this to be called.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)text
{
    //Check if a space follows a space
    if ( (range.location > 0 && [text length] > 0 &&
          [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[text characterAtIndex:0]] &&
          [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[[textField text] characterAtIndex:range.location - 1]]) )
    {
        //Manually replace the space with your own space, programmatically
        textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@" "];

        //Make sure you update the text caret to reflect the programmatic change to the text view
//      textField.selectedTextRange = NSMakeRange(range.location+1, 0);  

        //Tell Cocoa not to insert its space, because you've just inserted your own
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)validateEmail:(NSString *)inputText {
NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z][A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]*@[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9.-]*\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}"; 
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; 
NSRange aRange;
if([emailTest evaluateWithObject:inputText]) 
{
    aRange = [inputText rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [inputText length])];
    int indexOfDot = aRange.location;
    NSLog(@"aRange.location:%d - %d",aRange.location, indexOfDot);
    if(aRange.location != NSNotFound) 
    {
        NSString *topLevelDomain = [inputText substringFromIndex:indexOfDot];
        topLevelDomain = [topLevelDomain lowercaseString];
        NSLog(@"topleveldomains:%@",topLevelDomain);
        NSSet *TLD;
        TLD = [NSSet setWithObjects:@".aero", @".asia", @".biz", @".cat", @".com", @".coop", @".edu", @".gov", @".info", @".int", @".jobs", @".mil", @".mobi", @".museum", @".name", @".net", @".org", @".pro", @".tel", @".travel", @".ac", @".ad", @".ae", @".af", @".ag", @".ai", @".al", @".am", @".an", @".ao", @".aq", @".ar", @".as", @".at", @".au", @".aw", @".ax", @".az", @".ba", @".bb", @".bd", @".be", @".bf", @".bg", @".bh", @".bi", @".bj", @".bm", @".bn", @".bo", @".br", @".bs", @".bt", @".bv", @".bw", @".by", @".bz", @".ca", @".cc", @".cd", @".cf", @".cg", @".ch", @".ci", @".ck", @".cl", @".cm", @".cn", @".co", @".cr", @".cu", @".cv", @".cx", @".cy", @".cz", @".de", @".dj", @".dk", @".dm", @".do", @".dz", @".ec", @".ee", @".eg", @".er", @".es", @".et", @".eu", @".fi", @".fj", @".fk", @".fm", @".fo", @".fr", @".ga", @".gb", @".gd", @".ge", @".gf", @".gg", @".gh", @".gi", @".gl", @".gm", @".gn", @".gp", @".gq", @".gr", @".gs", @".gt", @".gu", @".gw", @".gy", @".hk", @".hm", @".hn", @".hr", @".ht", @".hu", @".id", @".ie", @" No", @".il", @".im", @".in", @".io", @".iq", @".ir", @".is", @".it", @".je", @".jm", @".jo", @".jp", @".ke", @".kg", @".kh", @".ki", @".km", @".kn", @".kp", @".kr", @".kw", @".ky", @".kz", @".la", @".lb", @".lc", @".li", @".lk", @".lr", @".ls", @".lt", @".lu", @".lv", @".ly", @".ma", @".mc", @".md", @".me", @".mg", @".mh", @".mk", @".ml", @".mm", @".mn", @".mo", @".mp", @".mq", @".mr", @".ms", @".mt", @".mu", @".mv", @".mw", @".mx", @".my", @".mz", @".na", @".nc", @".ne", @".nf", @".ng", @".ni", @".nl", @".no", @".np", @".nr", @".nu", @".nz", @".om", @".pa", @".pe", @".pf", @".pg", @".ph", @".pk", @".pl", @".pm", @".pn", @".pr", @".ps", @".pt", @".pw", @".py", @".qa", @".re", @".ro", @".rs", @".ru", @".rw", @".sa", @".sb", @".sc", @".sd", @".se", @".sg", @".sh", @".si", @".sj", @".sk", @".sl", @".sm", @".sn", @".so", @".sr", @".st", @".su", @".sv", @".sy", @".sz", @".tc", @".td", @".tf", @".tg", @".th", @".tj", @".tk", @".tl", @".tm", @".tn", @".to", @".tp", @".tr", @".tt", @".tv", @".tw", @".tz", @".ua", @".ug", @".uk", @".us", @".uy", @".uz", @".va", @".vc", @".ve", @".vg", @".vi", @".vn", @".vu", @".wf", @".ws", @".ye", @".yt", @".za", @".zm", @".zw", nil];
        if(topLevelDomain != nil && ([TLD containsObject:topLevelDomain])) 
        {
            //NSLog(@"TLD contains topLevelDomain:%@",topLevelDomain);
            return TRUE;
        }
//            else {
//             NSLog(@"TLD DOEST NOT contains topLevelDomain:%@",topLevelDomain);
//             }

    }
}
return FALSE;
}
```

**den chek**

```
if ([self validateEmail:txtFieldUserName.text]) 
{
    NSLog(@"done");
} 
else
{
 NSLog(@"Not done");
}
```

maybe it will help you... thanx...

Comment: Still if I press space twice, a full- stop appears after com :( ,but thatks for your efforts !! :)