# Not allow dot "." on double tap spacebar for UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextfield

I am facing problem in my app that, When I press space bar twice, "."(dot) gets added in the TextField. I do not want to allow dot "." on double tap spacebar.

**Note**: I know that it is default behaviour of textField in iOS.

I refered the earlier answer [iPhone: Disable the "double-tap spacebar for ." shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576561/iphone-disable-the-double-tap-spacebar-for-shortcut) but it is for textView, Not For textField.

I not getting replacement to this line

```
textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(range.location + 1, 0)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone: Disable the "double-tap spacebar for ." shortcut?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576561/iphone-disable-the-double-tap-spacebar-for-shortcut)

Comment: @Vishnugondlekar if you can provide me for  textfield version, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, then use the below delegate method, its was solved, use this code the dot not displayed in textfield,

swift Code:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let newString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string) as? NSString

        let arrayOfString = newString?.componentsSeparatedByString(".");
        if arrayOfString?.count > 1
        {
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
```

objective C code:

```
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString1 = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSArray  *arrayOfString1 = [newString1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    if ([arrayOfString1 count] > 1 )
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

its working for me, hope its helpful

Comment: please answer swift question with swift answers only.

Comment: func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    var newString1: String = textField.text!.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    var arrayOfString1: [AnyObject] = newString1.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
    if arrayOfString1.count > 1 {
        return false
    }
    return true
}

Comment: just use converter to check it (objective c -swift)  https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/

Comment: ok But All the time its not correct code, check your above code in xcode, its show range error.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
final class RestrictedDoubleSpaceDotTextField: UITextField {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangeText), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    @objc private func didChangeText() {
        let textWithoutDot = text?.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: " ", options: .literal, range: nil)
        text = textWithoutDot
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change Keyboard settings from simulator/iPhone.

In iPhone Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> (Turn Off) "." shortcut

Answer (score -2):

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
  if (string == ". ") {
    return false
  }
  else {
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: my question is about double tap spacebar

Comment: That does not work, characters are entered one at a time