# UITextField displays extra dot at the end of text

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I saw a very strange issue with UITextField control. When typing in UITextField after typing a few characters when typing space characters it puts "." characters at the end of the string.

Can anyone know possible solution for this??

Thanks,

Jim.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone SDK: disable auto creation of dot (.) in text field (or textview)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528049/iphone-sdk-disable-auto-creation-of-dot-in-text-field-or-textview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean when you enter 2 spaces? If so this a feature that means you don't need to switch to the numeric keyboard to enter the full stop

Comment: Yes i am talking about the same issue. This is feature rather than bug.