# When i hit the space bar a dot comes up in search bar place?

Tags: iphone

when the user search on the  search bar with blank space after entering some text then a dot is coming. For example when the user types:

```
Qq<spacebar><spacebar>
```

The result is:

```
Qq.
```

in the output we can see one dot. how its coming how we can remove the dot

Answer (score 1):

This is a shortcut built into iOS. From Apple's [iPhone 4 Tips and Tricks](http://www.apple.com/iphone/tips/) page:

> Tap the space bar twice, and iPhone adds a period and capitalizes the next word.

See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576561/iphone-disable-the-double-tap-spacebar-for-shortcut) two [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528049/iphone-sdk-disable-auto-creation-of-dot-in-text-field-or-textview) for potential solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It's the standard behavior of the input fields in iPhone. You can modify this behavior in your settings under:

> General ⇛ Keyboard ⇛ "." Shortcut ⇛ OFF

If you want to turn it off programmatically see [@Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144314/when-i-hit-the-space-bar-a-dot-comes-up-in-search-bar-place/7144359#answer-7144355).